# How would I Deserialize grouped JSON data with C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, deserialization

I have been struggling to deserialize this JSON string and I thought someone could help me.

This is the json;

```
{
  "22/7/2020": {
    "0": {
      "date": null,
      "time": "9:00 pm",
      "place": "London",
      "name": "Date night"
    },
    "1": {
      "date": null,
      "time": "2:30 pm",
      "place": "London",
      "name": "Lunch"
    }
  },
  "23/7/2020": {
    "0": {
      "date": null,
      "time": "1:00 pm",
      "place": "Cafe",
      "name": "Coffee Meeting"
    }
  },
  "24/7/2020": {
    "0": {
      "date": null,
      "time": "3:00 pm",
      "place": "London",
      "name": "Run"
    },
    "27/7/2020": {
      "0": {
        "date": null,
        "time": "6:00 pm",
        "place": "Mountains",
        "name": "Hiking"
      }
    },
    "30/7/2020": {
      "0": {
        "date": null,
        "time": "10:00 am",
        "place": "Solo Cafe",
        "name": "Brunch"
      }
    },
    "3/8/2020": {
      "0": {
        "date": null,
        "time": "8:00 pm",
        "place": "London",
        "name": "Drinks"
      },
      "1": {
        "date": null,
        "time": "11:00 am",
        "place": "Work",
        "name": "Work"
      },
      "2": {
        "date": null,
        "time": "6:00 pm",
        "place": "Grandma's",
        "name": "Dinner with Grandma"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the objects are grouped under the date element which creates this kind of nested structure and my problem is I don't know how to deserialize this into an object list. I tried doing it this way:

Using these two classes;

```
public class events_final
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<details> Event_Details { get; set; }
}
public class details
{
    [DataMember]
    public string date { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string time { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string place { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And doing this:

```
var Deserialized_Json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<details>>(json_string);
```

However, that didn't work and instead, I got all these errors:

```
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x003a0] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, System.Object existingValue) [0x0006d] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00054] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0002d] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me deserialize this into a list!

Comment: Your C# classes have to match the format of your JSON. You can't just set up an arbitrary object in C# and then be like "OK, JSON.NET. Go figure it out.". Perhaps you should try deserializing to a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, details>>`?

Comment: That's going to be tricky, your json field names are really arbitrary dates.  I'd try like John said, or you'll have to use some custom code

Answer (score 2):

Given your corrected json, it was munted in various ways (sigh)

```
var input = @"
{
   ""22/7/2020"":{
      ""0"":{
         ""date"":null,
         ""time"":""9:00 pm"",
         ""place"":""London"",
         ""name"":""Date night""
      },
      ""1"":{
         ""date"":null,
         ""time"":""2:30 pm"",
         ""place"":""London"",
         ""name"":""Lunch""
      }
   },
   ""23/7/2020"":{
      ""0"":{
         ""date"":null,
         ""time"":""1:00 pm"",
         ""place"":""Cafe"",
         ""name"":""Coffee Meeting""
      }
   },
   ""24/7/2020"":{
      ""0"":{
         ""date"":null,
         ""time"":""3:00 pm"",
         ""place"":""London"",
         ""name"":""Run""
      }
   },
   ""27/7/2020"":{
      ""0"":{
         ""date"":null,
         ""time"":""6:00 pm"",
         ""place"":""Mountains"",
         ""name"":""Hiking""
      }
   },
   ""30/7/2020"":{
      ""0"":{
         ""date"":null,
         ""time"":""10:00 am"",
         ""place"":""Solo Cafe"",
         ""name"":""Brunch""
      }
   },
   ""3/8/2020"":{
      ""0"":{
         ""date"":null,
         ""time"":""8:00 pm"",
         ""place"":""London"",
         ""name"":""Drinks""
      },
      ""1"":{
         ""date"":null,
         ""time"":""11:00 am"",
         ""place"":""Work"",
         ""name"":""Work""
      },
      ""2"":{
         ""date"":null,
         ""time"":""6:00 pm"",
         ""place"":""Grandma's"",
         ""name"":""Dinner with Grandma""
      }
   }
}";
```

**Usage**

```
var results = JsonConvert
   .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, details>>>(input)
   .SelectMany(x =>
      x.Value.Select(y =>
         new details
         {
            date = x.Key,
            time = y.Value.time,
            place = y.Value.place,
            name = y.Value.name
         }));

foreach (var r in results)
   Console.WriteLine($"{r.date}, {r.time}, {r.place}, {r.name}");
```

**Output**

```
22/7/2020, 9:00 pm, London, Date night
22/7/2020, 2:30 pm, London, Lunch
23/7/2020, 1:00 pm, Cafe, Coffee Meeting
24/7/2020, 3:00 pm, London, Run
27/7/2020, 6:00 pm, Mountains, Hiking
30/7/2020, 10:00 am, Solo Cafe, Brunch
3/8/2020, 8:00 pm, London, Drinks
3/8/2020, 11:00 am, Work, Work
3/8/2020, 6:00 pm, Grandma's, Dinner with Grandma
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer of The General(Admiral General Aladeen), I have an alternate but not so efficient answer for the problem above (just want to point an additional solution for this problem), You can use `ExpandoObject` to deserialize and then loop through the data.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonStringAbove);
```

And then loop through the object like this:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    var date = item.Key;
    foreach (var item1 in (ExpandoObject)item.Value)
    {
        foreach (var item2 in (ExpandoObject)item1.Value)
        {
            if (item2.Key.Equals("date"))
            {
                Console.Write($"{date} ");
                continue;
            }
            Console.Write($"{item2.Key} - {item2.Value}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
22/7/2020 time - 9:00 pm place - London name - Date night
22/7/2020 time - 2:30 pm place - London name - Lunch
23/7/2020 time - 1:00 pm place - Cafe name - Coffee Meeting
24/7/2020 time - 3:00 pm place - London name - Run
27/7/2020 time - 6:00 pm place - Mountains name - Hiking
30/7/2020 time - 10:00 am place - Solo Cafe name - Brunch
3/8/2020 time - 8:00 pm place - London name - Drinks
3/8/2020 time - 11:00 am place - Work name - Work
3/8/2020 time - 6:00 pm place - Grandma's name - Dinner with Grandma
```

---

I see, you want a list out of the results, you can achieve it like this:

```
List<details> listDetails = new List<details>();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    foreach (var item1 in (ExpandoObject)item.Value)
    {
        var detail = new details { date = item.Key };
        foreach (var item2 in (ExpandoObject)item1.Value)
        {
            if (item2.Key == "time")
            {
                detail.time = item2.Value.ToString();
            }
            else if (item2.Key == "place")
            {
                detail.place = item2.Value.ToString();
            }
            else if (item2.Key == "name")
            {
                detail.name = item2.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        listDetails.Add(detail);
    }
}
```